# emberjs how to add external js files

Tags: ember.js

I am novice to ember.js, This is how I have included my external java script file to ember project to call to jquery plugin in imagerotator.js

```
<script src="{{rootURL}}assets/imagerotator/html/js/imagerotator.js"></script>
```

when I am calling it from the document.ready() function it getting initialized properly.

But I need that plugin should be only in only one hadlerbar(.hbs) file.
Am I doing it correctly ?

I heard there is a "didInsertElement" function in components file and define there but in my case I don't have component just have template file only.

I am novice to emberjs and sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place `imagerotator/html/js/imagerotator.js` file in `vendor` folder and include it in `ember-cli-build.js` file by `app.import('vendor/imagerotator/html/js/imagerotator.js');`

It good to create component and initialize it in `didInsertElement` hook.